# How to set specific font-version (e.g. Font Awesome) in i3wm config files

Tags: fonts, i3

I use i3wm with the i3status bar. My configuration file uses "`FontAwesome 10`" font specification for displaying various icons in the bar. Now a new Version of [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet) is around. When I, as before, copy-paste the icons into the `config`-files they are not recognized because i3wm is sourcing the old version of the font (4.7.0).

[image]

I have installed the new version (5.7.2), however it is not used by i3wm. Can I force/specify i3 to use a certain font version? How?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what OS you're on (I use Ubuntu, currently 18.04), but for me if `apt` package hasn't updated to the newest FontAwesome version, I manually download the newest package from the site.

- I save the new `.otf` files in `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/font-awesome/`
- I save the new `.eot`, `.svg`, `.ttf`, `.woff`, `.woof2` files in `/usr/share/fonts-font-awesome/fonts`

Be sure to reload the font cache with `sudo fc-cache -f -v`.

As an aside, I also recommend at least looking into [polybar](https://github.com/jaagr/polybar). It's really flexible, and it works perfectly with FontAwesome as well. I moved from i3status bar quite a while ago now.

Answer (score 0):

You could override your system fonts with new version installed locally. Download new font version and unpack it into `~/.local/share/fonts/`. Then check that font cache is updated:

```
$ fc-list |grep Awesome
/home/user/.local/share/fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf: Font Awesome 5 Free,Font Awesome 5 Free Solid:style=Solid
/home/user/.local/share/fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf: Font Awesome 5 Free,Font Awesome 5 Free Regular:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/font-awesome/FontAwesome.otf: FontAwesome:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/woff/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff: FontAwesome:style=Regular
/home/user/.local/share/fonts/Font Awesome 5 Brands-Regular-400.otf: Font Awesome 5 Brands,Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf: FontAwesome:style=Regular
```

You may need to restart `i3status` after that.